# Mysql php count number of inner join work faster with subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

Two tables, first one is users and 2nd is posts, table posts structure is `id,body,parent_id,user_id` in this table all posts are inserted with parent_id is null, and if its a comment the parent_id is set to post id.

What I'm trying to do is join users table -to get user details- and get count of comments on each post.

I tried a couple of queries

```
select  p.id,
        users.id as 'from_id',
        users.fullname as 'from_fullname',
        users.role as 'from_role',
        users.picture as 'from_picture',
        p.body,
        p.time_posted as 'time_posted',
        p.attachment,
        p.parent_id,
        count(c.id) as counts
from 
    wall p
join   
    users on users.id = p.user_id
left join 
    wall c on c.parent_id = p.id
where 
    p.class_id = 8 and p.parent_id is null
group by 
    p.id
order by
    `counts` ---->EXPLAIN RESULTS

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  p   ref PRIMARY,parent_id,class_id,user_id  parent_id   5   const   49920   Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  users   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ischool.p.user_id   1   NULL
1   SIMPLE  c   ref parent_id   parent_id   5   ischool.p.id    49920   Using index
```

This one takes average of around 2.7 sec to complete.

While my 2nd attempt

```
select  p.id,
        users.id as 'from_id',
        users.fullname as 'from_fullname',
        users.role as 'from_role',
        users.picture as 'from_picture',
        p.body,
        (select count(*) from wall where parent_id= p.id ) as comments_count,
        p.time_posted as 'time_posted',
        p.attachment,
        p.parent_id
from 
    wall p
left join 
    users on users.id = p.user_id
where 
    p.class_id = 8 and p.parent_id is NULL
order by 
    p.id DESC; --->Explain results

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY p   ref parent_id,class_id  parent_id   5   const   49920   Using where
1   PRIMARY users   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ischool.p.user_id   1   NULL
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  wall    ref parent_id   parent_id   5   ischool.p.id    49920   Using index
```

This query takes 1.4 sec to complete

given that im using MYSQL innodb with index on each and every id column.

1. so is there a better method to fetch posts and comment counts ?
2. why is subquery working nearly 2x faster than join ?

Comment: Any time you want to know anything about query performance, you have to start with the EXPLAIN, and proper DDLs for all relevant tables.

Comment: @Strawberry yp did that, didnt exactly understood what explain returned , i will edit question with result

Comment: Of course most of the time join will be faster than sub-query especially inner join, in sub-query mysql will fetch all the rows in each main query iteration, then filter it later on main query, while join query directly filter the rows and fetch only the rows that pass the filter.

Comment: Also note that more indexes does not equate to faster performance- but better indexes might.

Answer (score -2):

Basically Joins are more faster than sub query. Generally, new developer prefers to use sub-query.

The execution plan of query may impact on performance. Almost all cases queries joins are more faster than sub-query.

The basic difference is that sub-query execute query and load all data and based on those data execute another query.

and joins are all tables all loads with data so it performs fast execution of query.

In you query, if you want to show why you sub-query is faster than join use "explain " command to show how query is actually executed.

Following links may helpful to understand concepts:
http://www.chrislondon.co/joins-vs-subqueries/
http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Comment: ehhm, i already did and posted the explain result in question. i dont see how you are answering anything.

Comment: This is far too simplistic to be useful or true

Comment: @Strawberry / Zalaboza : it's not my fault that you sent same post on same time and you have not rights not denied and give negative vote on my answer.

Comment: If you are not able to explain the things like me it's not my fault.

Comment: I had explained what do you want to in brief, play real with truth.

Comment: @Zalaboza : where do you write about explain if you know everything then why do you post on stack overflow and waste time.

Comment: Explain statement result follow query code in the question.

Comment: @Dipakchavda you seem very angry, but I'm not sure why. Consider re-reading Chris London's blog. His conclusion is the opposite of yours. I cannot think of an example where it would make sense to use a subquery in place of an INNER JOIN, but any time an (uncorellated) subquery goes up against an OUTER JOIN, I'd be willing to bet that (appropriately indexed) the subquery will be faster - at least for the most recent verions of MySQL.